# updating mongodb using meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

im new to meteor and im trying to create gantt chart using dhtmlx pckage dhtmlx:gantt

everything works fine writing to the db when i have the insecure and autopublish, however when i remove them i use the publish methods. strange the insert and remove works but the update i get error message "update failed: access denied. In a restricted collection you can only update documents, not replace them.
use a Mongo update operator, such as '$set'

**below is my client folder code
gantt.html :**

```
<head>
  <title>gantt</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> Gantt}}
</body>

<template name="Gantt">
  <div id="gantt_here" style='width: 100%; height: 400px;'></div>
</template>
```

client/gant.js:

```
Template.Gantt.rendered = function() {
gantt.init("gantt_here");
gantt.meteor({tasks: TasksCollection, links: LinksCollection});
gantt.config.scale_unit = "month";
gantt.config.step = 1;
gantt.config.date_scale = "%M";
gantt.config.start_date = new Date(2016, 01, 01);
gantt.config.end_date = new Date(2016, 12, 30);
gantt.init("gantt_here");

};
```

**client/subscribe.js:**

```
Meteor.subscribe("links");
Meteor.subscribe("tasks");
```

**in server**

```
Meteor.publish("links", function(){
  return LinksCollection.find();
});

Meteor.publish("tasks", function(){
  return TasksCollection.find();
});
```

**in collection folder:**

```
TasksCollection = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
LinksCollection = new Mongo.Collection('links');

TasksCollection.allow({
    insert: function () { return true; },
    update: function () { return true; },
    remove: function () { return true; },
});


LinksCollection.allow({
    insert: function () { return true; },
    update: function () { return true; },
    remove: function () { return true; },
});
```

can someone help me

Comment: Where is your code that shows where you're trying to actually update or insert into the collections?

Comment: Like @thatgibbyguy we need to see your update event, to see how it looks, but also it will be good to know how the documents looks before the update i.e {_id: "someID", foo: "bar"}, and which field are you trying to update, seems like it could be that you are not making good the update. try to follow this syntax `LinksCollection.update({_id:"someId"}, {$set:{foo:'bar'}})`

Comment: it displays gantt chart which visually you manipulate the chart like the below image

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/1031343/task-gantt-meteor.png

i dont have control on how do i update the database